# EOS Block Explorer

Tags: blockchains

I have a local EOS testnet running and I am trying to run this [block explorer](https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSTracker.git) against my EOS local testnet.

I launch `https://localhost:4200` in a browser and look at the nodeos output terminal. Here is what I see repeating, in nodeos output terminal, when viewing the EOSTracker Dashboard in my browser:

```
1168686ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:186           handle_http_request  ] 404 - not found: /stats
1168688ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:186           handle_http_request  ] 404 - not found: /blocks?size=20
1168689ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:186           handle_http_request  ] 404 - not found: /transactions?size=20
```

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think EOSTracker as today is outdated. It used mongodb_plugin which is deprecated for now. the best person to answer this is @kesarito